How to combine YOLO model for detection with a different CNN for classification?
Working on a project where I'm planning on utilising YOLOv8 for object detection and a separate model for classification purposes. My question is, after training the YOLO model, how do I proceed on combining the two models?
Have so far trained the YOLO for object detection.

The question is...why?  Are you using YOLO for example to find "dice" and then hoping to use something else to tell you if it is 1, 2, 3, ...?
If you are, then I suggest you take a step back.  Instead of training your network to find dice why not train it  with classes such as 1, 2, 3, etc?  Then the result from YOLO is the final result you're hoping to get.
And if all of that does not describe your situation, then please update the question with more details.  Include an example image, describe what output you're expecting to get.
